# Entailment in one-point extensions of standard-enough models

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

*This is one of two questions about the power of "one-point extensions" in reverse mathematics. This one focuses on what separations can be achieved as one-point extensions of as-closed-as-desired $\omega$-models; the other focuses on when one-point extensions can get one separation from another separation, and is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445857/bootstrapping-separation-results-via-one-point-extensions).*

---

Let $\mathfrak{N}_2=(\omega\sqcup\mathcal{P}(\omega);+,\cdot,0,1,<,\in)$ be the standard model of second-order arithmetic. I'm interested in what separations in the sense of reverse mathematics can be achieved by adding a single real to (something very like) $\mathfrak{N}_2$. Towards that end, for $M$ an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ and $r$ a real, let $M^r$ be the $\omega$-model whose second-order part is the smallest Turing ideal containing $M\cup\{r\}$ as a subset.

For $\varphi,\psi$ sentences in the language of second-order arithmetic, write $\varphi\models_1\psi$ iff for every countable *(to avoid pathologies that aren't my primary interest here)* $M\prec\mathfrak{N}_2$ and every real $r$, if $M^r\models\varphi$ then $M^r\models\psi$. Meanwhile, let $\models_{\underline{\omega}}$ be the restriction of the usual $\models$ to countable $\omega$-models *on a cone* - that is, $\varphi\models_{\underline{\omega}}\psi$ iff there is some real $r$ such that every countable $\omega$-model of $\varphi$ containing $r$ also satisfies $\psi$.

> **Question**: Do $\models_1$ and $\models_{\underline{\omega}}$ coincide?

The use of $\models_{\underline{\omega}}$ as opposed to $\models$ restricted to countable $\omega$-models is just in order to rule out trivial counterexamples such as $\varphi =$ "$0'$ exists" and $\psi = $ "$0''$ exists."

For example, at a glance I believe it is the case that $\mathsf{ACA}_0\not\models_1\mathsf{ATR_0}$ - basically, given a countable $M\prec\mathfrak{N}_2$, we can build a "finitely generic but not $\omega$-generic" real $r$ relative to $M$, and then $M^r$ satisfies $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ but doesn't contain $r^{(\omega)}$. However, the details are a bit messy and I'm not sure I got it right. Certainly I see no reason for $\models_1$ and $\models_{\underline{\omega}}$ to coincide all the time, but I also can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict to countable models $M$? Things get a bit weird when $M$ is uncountable.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Indeed I do. Fixed!

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais And I've made the same fix at this question's sibling. Thanks again!